# Conditional "Or" Statements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am under the impression that || is the "or" statement in MATLAB. Perhaps someone can explain the confusing behaviour I am seeing:

```
a = 2;

a == 2        %returns ans = 1 (true)

a == 2 || 3   %returns ans = 1 (true)

a == 3 || 4   %returns ans = 1 (true)??!!
```

What am I missing here? 'a' is neither 3 or 4, so shouldn't

```
a == 3 || 4
```

return ans = 0 (false)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression

```
a == 3 || 4
```

is evaluated that way :

```
a == 3     => false
then
false || 4 => true
```

if you want to check whether a is equal to 3 or 4 you should write

```
(a == 3) || (a == 4)
```

which is evaluated that way

```
a == 3         => false
then
a == 4         => false
then
false || false => false
```

Answer (score 0):

Thomas's answer is an excellent explanation of what's going on here; another way that you can compare a variable to multiple answers is using the [any()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) function.

```
solutions = [3 4];
any(a==solutions);
```

The `a==solutions` line creates a matrix the same size as solutions, which contains 1's in indecies which where the conditional is true, and 0's where it is false.

A few more examples:

```
any(isprime([17:24])); %returns true; 17, 19 and 23 are prime
any(isinteger(sqrt([17:24]))); %(test for square number) returns false; no square numbers in this range
any(mod(magic(3)(:),6)==3); %returns true; 9 mod 6 == 3. Note (:) inserted so that any is evaluated against all entries of the square matrix created by magic
```

Answer (score 0):

> `a == 3 || 4   %returns ans = 1 (true)`??!!

The reason for the above behaviour is due to the fact that any real number other than '0' in MATLAB is always evaluated to true.

So what is happening here is

- The expression `a == 3` is evaluated first and found to be `false`.
- Next, expression `false || 4` is evaluated.
- Since '4' is a real number other than zero, the resulting expression is `false || true` which is evaluated to `true`.

To get a desire result use `(a == 3) || (a == 4)` which is evaluated as `false || false` which returns `false`.